# importing database and get row size error

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

> 1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline

[image]

when I go to import database in my localhost xampp server, it's not uploading all table and giving this error

Comment: So what do you want us to do about that?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: click variables button

Step 2: Search "innodb strict mode"

Step 3: clieck Edit button

Step 4: if it's "ON" then make it "OFF" and save it.

Now your problem is solved, you can try to import your database again!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVB01.png)